# Django daphne при вызове view открывается новый поток

Tags: python, django, асинхронность, threading, asgi

Всем здравствуйте, совсем недавно обнаружил для себя интересную деталь.

Каждый раз когда я вызываю view функцию, она запускается не в основном потоке, а для нее создается новый (Схожее поведение я наблюдал при запуске через `manage.py runserver`)

Я не совсем уверен в том что это правильное поведение daphne и не уверен в том что я делаю все правильно.

Предполагаю что с этим могут быть связаны воркеры, но их создание:

```
start /b python manage.py runworker websocket http
```

ни к чему не приводило.

Слезно прошу подсказать в правильном ли я направлении двигаюсь и на что мне нужно обратить внимание. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Если view-функция не асинхронная, то так и должно быть

Comment: @andreymal, проблема в том что она как раз асинхронная :D

Comment: И никакими декораторами не оборачивается

Comment: Подцепился к функции `sync_to_async` и увидел, что она вызывается для middleware, для сигналов и для HttpResponseBase.close — похоже, поддержка асинхронщины в Django всё ещё далека от идеальной... Но как минимум можно попробовать избавиться от синхронных middleware, чтобы ситуация стала чуточку лучше

Comment: @andreymal, понял, спасибо